# fs.rename(new Path(rawFileName), new Path(processFileName)) is not working

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop2, hadoop-partitioning

I am working on Scala based Apache Spark implementation for data onboarding from remote location to HDFS and then on data ingestion from HDFS to Hive tables.

Using my first spark job I have onboarded the data/files into HDFS at a location say -

> hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/data/analytics/raw/ folder

Let's consider that after onboarding CT_Click_Basic.csv and CT_Click_Basic1.csv.gz files I have following files in HDFS [file names at shared location would be a folder name here and its content would be present in part-xxxxx files]:

> [root@sandbox ~]# hdfs dfs -ls /data/analytics/raw/*/
> Found 3 items
>
> -rw-r--r--   3 chauhan.bhupesh hdfs          0 2017-07-27 15:02 /data/analytics/raw/CT_Click_Basic.csv/_SUCCESS
>
> -rw-r--r--   3 chauhan.bhupesh hdfs       8383 2017-07-27 15:02 /data/analytics/raw/CT_Click_Basic.csv/part-00000
>
> -rw-r--r--   3 chauhan.bhupesh hdfs       8395 2017-07-27 15:02 /data/analytics/raw/CT_Click_Basic.csv/part-00001
>
> Found 2 items
>
> -rw-r--r--   3 chauhan.bhupesh hdfs          0 2017-07-27 15:02 /data/analytics/raw/CT_Click_Basic1.csv.gz/_SUCCESS
>
> -rw-r--r--   3 chauhan.bhupesh hdfs      16588 2017-07-27 15:02 /data/analytics/raw/CT_Click_Basic1.csv.gz/part-00000

Now using my another Spark Job, I want to move these files as it is from **/raw** folder to **/process** and then finally to **/archive** folder in HDFS based on tasks performed at each stage.

For doing that I am first fetching list of all the files present under **/raw** folder using following code:

```
    def listAllFilesFolderInDir(filePath:String,recursiveTraverse:Boolean,filePaths: ListBuffer[Path]) : ListBuffer[Path] = {
val files = GlobalContext.hdfs.listStatus(new Path(filePath))
files.foreach { fileStatus => {
           if(!fileStatus.isDirectory()) {
                filePaths+=fileStatus.getPath()      
            }
            else {
                listAllFilesFolderInDir(fileStatus.getPath().toString(), recursiveTraverse, filePaths)
            }
        }
  }   
  filePaths
}
```

and then using following line of codes, I am trying to rename/move the files in /raw folder to /process folder:

```
var inputDir = "/data/analytics/raw"
var outputDir = "/data/analytics/process"
var filePaths = new ListBuffer[Path]()
var pathArray = listAllFilesFolderInDir(inputDir, true, filePaths)
val fs= <Getting hdfs FileSystem Instance Here>
for(path<-pathArray){
   var pathSplit = path.toString().split("/")
   var pathSplitSize = pathSplit.size
   val rawFileName = inputDir + "/" + pathSplit(pathSplitSize-2) + "/" + pathSplit(pathSplitSize-1)
   val processFileName = outputDir + "/" + pathSplit(pathSplitSize-2) + "/" + pathSplit(pathSplitSize-1)
   fs.rename(new Path(rawFileName), new Path(processFileName))
 }
```

But I am not able to move/rename these files using above written code. I tried debugging the code and found that fs.rename() is returning me "false".

> Please Note: I am able to achieve the file renaming/movement when I copy any file manually in /data/analytics/raw folder ex CT.csv [or any other file]
> and then running fs.rename() but it is not working for Part-xxxxx files.

Is there something which I am missing?

Any quick help will be appreciated.

Regards,
Bhupesh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I have got the issue. Actually I was trying to rename file from /data/analytics/raw/folder.csv/part-xxxxx to /data/analytics/process/folder.csv/part-xxxxx where /data/analytics/process was present in HDFS but "folder.csv" was not present; hence it was returning me false while renaming. I have added following line in my code and worked fine for me

```
var inputDir = "/data/analytics/raw"
var outputDir = "/data/analytics/process"
var filePaths = new ListBuffer[Path]()
var pathArray = listAllFilesFolderInDir(inputDir, true, filePaths)
val fs= <Getting hdfs FileSystem Instance Here>
for(path<-pathArray){
   var pathSplit = path.toString().split("/")
   var pathSplitSize = pathSplit.size

   val rawFileName = inputDir + "/" + pathSplit(pathSplitSize-2) + "/" + pathSplit(pathSplitSize-1)

   var processFolderName = outputDir + "/" + pathSplit(pathSplitSize-2)
   var processFolderPath = new Path(processFolderName)
   if(!(fs.exists(processFolderPath)))
         fs.mkdirs(processFolderPath)
   val processFileName = processFolderName + "/" + pathSplit(pathSplitSize-1)
   fs.rename(new Path(rawFileName), new Path(processFileName))
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Rename can returns false if new Path(rawFileName) doesn't exists.
Before fs.rename make check that file exists:

```
if (fs.exists(somePath)) {
 fs.rename...
}
```

Another cause may be that file which you try to rename is used by someone.    Or if you try to rename directory some files in it can be used by someone.
To make sure that this is the root cause try to rename something else files in your code:

```
var inputDir = "/data/analytics/raw"
var outputDir = "/data/analytics/process"
var filePaths = new ListBuffer[Path]()
var pathArray = listAllFilesFolderInDir(inputDir, true, filePaths)
val fs= <Getting hdfs FileSystem Instance Here>
for(path<-pathArray){
   var pathSplit = path.toString().split("/")
   var pathSplitSize = pathSplit.size
   val rawFileName = inputDir + "/" + pathSplit(pathSplitSize-2) + "/" + pathSplit(pathSplitSize-1)
   val processFileName = outputDir + "/" + pathSplit(pathSplitSize-2) + "/" + pathSplit(pathSplitSize-1)
   fs.rename(new Path("**/TESTDIR1**"), new Path("**/TESTDIR2**"))
 }
```

if this rename will be success the root cause is really in race condition.